# C# Emgucv turn off webcam

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv

currently my program can open the webcam then dynamic capture the human face, however, I have no idea how to stop the camera because it will keep capturing the face even the windows are closed.

```
private static VideoCapture _cameraCapture;

public VideoSurveilance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Run();

    }


    void Run()
    {

        try
        {
            _cameraCapture = new VideoCapture();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return;
        }

        _fgDetector = new 
        Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
        _blobDetector = new CvBlobDetector();
        _tracker = new CvTracks();

        Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
    }

    private void btnStopCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _cameraCapture.Pause();//not working
        _cameraCapture.Stop();//not working
        _cameraCapture.Dispose();//worked but crashed due to memory issue

        this.Close();

        faceManipulate fm = new faceManipulate();
        fm.Show();
```

Memory issue already solved. However, Dispose will cause the process frame Null Reference Object.

```
void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mat frame = _cameraCapture.QueryFrame();
        Mat smoothedFrame = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(frame, smoothedFrame, new Size(3, 3), 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved the issue, you should call the Dispose method.

CameraCapture implements DisposableObject, you should not have it as a static variable, instead you should keep it as a variable and dispose when you are done with it.

I saw that you said that it "worked but crashed due to memory issue", if this is still a problem post a question or comment below describing the memory issue.

Comment: Thx. Is it possible to stop the ProcessFrame method?

Comment: You should check if _cameraCapture != null before trying to queryFrame

Comment: Thank you.....problem solved. As you said need to check the _cameraCapture using if else statement.

Comment: Glad I could help you, please accept the answer to avoid other people thinking this still needs an answer

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this code challenge is old and not many solutions have been posted at this time. However, the provided response will not really solve the issue. I encountered the same problem and found a way around it to avoid the memory `NullReferenceError`. I will use my own code here for convenience, but the challenges are the same, so it applies. Pick the code section that applies to your instance.

MY OBSERVATIONS

1. Any `Bitmap` object has to be disposed (`bitmap.Dispose()`)
   properly to free the memory from overload. The natural garbage
   collector seems not to pick it up at the end of its function.
2. The `Emgu.CV.Capture _capture;` object has to be disposed
   (`_capture.Dsipose()`) as well but has to be done with boolean control to avoid a `NullReference` error.

   ```
   public partial class Main : Form
   {
       bool isStreaming;
       bool onCamera;
       Capture _capture;

       public Main()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           onCamera = false;
           isStreaming = false;
           if (_capture != null) _capture.Dispose();
           if (picStream.Image != null) picStream.Image = null;
           if (picCapture.Image != null) picCapture.Image = null;
       }

       private void btnStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               onCamera = true;
               if (_capture != null) _capture.Dispose();
               _capture = new Capture();
               labelStatus.Text = "Streaming...";
               isStreaming = true;
               StreamVideo();
               Application.Idle += Streaming;
           }
           catch {}
       }

       private void Streaming(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               if(onCamera && isStreaming)
               {
                   if (picStream.Image != null) picStream.Image = null;

                   var img = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
                   var bmp = img.Bitmap;
                   picStream.Image = bmp;
               }
           }
           catch {}            
       }

       private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           onCamera = true;
           CaptureImage();
           labelStatus.Text = "Captured!";
           if (picCapture.Image != null) picCapture.Image = null;     
           picCapture.Image = picStream.Image;
       }            

       private void btnLoadCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               if (!isStreaming)
               {
                   _capture = new Capture();
                   StreamVideo();
                   pnlStatus.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
               }
               else
               {
                   _capture.Dispose();
                   Application.Idle -= Streaming;
                   picStream.Visible = true;
                   picStream.Image = null;
                   picCapture.Visible = false;
                   picCapture.Image = null;
                   isStreaming = false;
                   pnlStatus.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
               }
           }
           catch {}            
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You can also use the elvis operator to shorten the null checks on the capture device:
_capture?.Dispose();